# Form with managed_file value as link in email

Tags: forms, hooks, files, emails

Like the title says I want to make managed_file value to be a link on form submissions in the email.

Webform has this option. When a user uploads file, on the email form submission there's a link with the path of the uploaded file. I want to achieve this with custom module.
This is my code:

```
<?php

function mymodule_page($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['description'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => t('Add description'),
    );
    $form['file'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file', 
        '#title' => t('Upload image'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://files',

    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#submit' => array('mymodule_page_submit'),
    );

    return $form;
}

function mymodule_page_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['file']);
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);

    //dpm($file);

    $description = $form_state['values']['description'];

    $params = array('file' => $file->uri, 'description' => $description ); 
    drupal_mail('mymodule', 'mymodule_news_mail', 'myemail', language_default(), $params);
    drupal_set_message(t('Message sent!')); 
}

/*
** Implements hook_mail().
*/
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    switch($key) {    
        case 'mymodule_news_mail':
            $message['subject'] = t('Hello');
            $message['body'][] = t('This is a test');
            $message['body'][] = t('Image upload: @file', array('@file' => $params['file']));
            $message['body'][] = t('Description: @description', array('@description' => $params['description']));   
        break;    
    }
}
```

As you can see it from my code I'm saving the file properly into the server. After that with dpm($file->uri) I can see the string public://files/file_name.

How can I display the link from the path of the uploaded file on the email, so will be able to click on the absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jaypan from drupal.org, I've got the answer:

```
<?php
file_create_url($file->uri);
?>
```

Simply with adding this code and make another variable that will use the code, I've got the right result.